# form need shows from the models.py

Tags: django-models, django-forms

every one ,,I have

> models.py

```
......
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    release = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductsTbl(models.Model):
    ......   
    place = models.ManyToManyField(Place)
    ......

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

and I have forms.py here

> forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *


    class ProductsTblForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = ProductsTbl
            fields = ('place',)


    ......
```

however,,I need let my templates shows the 'release' in form,,right now,,it only shows the 'name' which under the Class place(models.Model): but no 'release',,how can I let the 'release' can show up?

Answer (score 0):

You can access model instance variables in the form by using `form.instance.<field_name>`.

Comment: you mean in views.py ?

Comment: You can do that in your view and in your template. But since it's a `ManyToManyField`, you should use `place_set` to access the manager for that field.